# Multi-column label in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following markup in a form.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                States
                <img id="clear-selection" src="~/images/delete.png" title="Clear Selection" />
            </label>
            <select class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The control label (*States*) is followed by an icon. But I would really like the icon to be aligned to the right.

Instead of this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this within the intended framework of Twitter Bootstrap? I'm not really clear about what sort of Bootstrap styles are considered acceptable within a `<label>` tag.

Comment: You can try adding ```pull-right``` class to your image.

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal: No, that has no effect.

Comment: Change label ```display``` css attribute from ```inline-block``` to ```initial```

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal: Well, that certainly would not be *"within the intended framework of Twitter Bootstrap"*.

Comment: You are allowed to change the HTML structure, right?

Comment: @m4n0: Yes, I'd just like to keep it within Bootstrap as much as possible rather than adding a bunch of custom styling that may be incompatible with future versions of Bootstrap.

Comment: The Labels are `inline-block`, so the label isn't actually that wide compared to `block` which is. You could in theory (I haven't tested it) move the image above outside of the label, then set it to pull-right. You can also give the label a custom class of say `block-label` and set `label.block-label{display:block;}` (you might need the dreaded `!important` after block also). By using a custom class, its simple, clean, minimal and only affects that one specific label and won't hurt future versions.

Comment: @imvain2: Putting the image above the label makes the image appear before it. Setting the image display to block puts in on a new line. And giving the image the pull-right class has no effect.

Comment: @JonathanWood even with the image having pull-right?

Comment: @imvain2: Adding the pull-right class has absolutely no effect on the `<img>` tag. Then again, the browser doesn't seem to show any settings for that class.

Comment: @imvain2: Oh, looks like you meant `float-right`. That seems to work. I don't need the `display: block` though. What does that do?

Comment: Ahh `pull-right` is from Bootstrap 3, I didn't realize they changed it. Display block on the label would have made it go all the way across the screen, which would allowed you to have the image aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this simply by moving the image above and outside of the label and giving it a class of `float-right`.

This will float the image to right.

Comment: Thanks. For me, setting the image to `display: block` has no visible effect. I removed this and the right side of the image lines up with the right side of the control below, which I want. Of course, I'm always concerned it's going to look differently on another browser or system.

Comment: @JonathanWood I apologize for the confusion, I was talking about making the label display block not the image.

Comment: I can't see any difference applying `display: block` to the `<label>` either.